# What are common Media Library tools used for Kentico/Generic PHP sites?

Tags: images, php, library

Through a course of mergers and acquisitions the particular group of companies who I work for have built up a vast array of websites running either Kentico (or ASP websites that *will* be using Kentico) and Generically produced PHP websites.

There is no DAM (Digital Asset Management) and our holding company wants to keep all the identities apart, so you can imagine the blood bath that ensues around marketing endeavours.

**What Media Library solutions are there which will work on both the Kentico CMS and for Hand-written PHP?**

We use approval/versioning and some sites will soon be large enough to need CDNs (so some form of link referencing is needed).

There are three scenarios where other solutions have fallen down:

1. Page a uses image z, page b uses image z, image z is updated and page a/b instantly use the updated image z instead of going through the approval process.
2. Page a uses image z, page b uses image z, image z is updated, page a's update is approved and instantly page b has the updated image z instead of going through the approval process.
3. Page a uses image z, page b uses image z, image z is updated, page a's update is approved, page b's update is approved, suddenly we need to go back to the previous version of page a and the older version of image z is no longer there.

The added pain is that we need a central image library to hold things like model sign offs and past marketing compaign usage to avoid clashes between the brands.

Comment: Kentico = http://www.kentico.com/ ?

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: Kentico has its own Media Gallery. So they're probably not going to support a third-party tool natively. You can watch the Kentico Marketplace http://devnet.kentico.com/Marketplace/Integration.aspx for an extension, but I don't see any suitable ones there for you right now. More than likely, you'll have to extend Kentico to support whatever solution you go with.

Comment: Hi @Metalshark, I am looking at a near identical issue at my company. Can I ask if you solved this issue with Kentico, or of you came up with another solution?

Comment: @TimC we no longer use Kentico however Picasa is doing a great job of DAM with CDN support.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot vouche for Kentico, since that is ASP.net based, and what you are looking at might run you into compatibility issues mixing PHP into the mix.

For PHP, [UltraPanel PRO](http://www.ultrapanelpro.com) would handle overloading all your static and dynamic pages just as you described as a CMS system.

Honestly, if I was a developer and a client asked me to build a site that uses both PHP and ASP.net, I would decline. They are two different kinds of scripting languages and two different kind of web platforms. This applies across the board to both file permissions and script access to URL formatting and form submits to JSON and AJAX handlers to database connections and query usage.

Really the only common interface you have is image and video stores along with the supporting CSS files for templates. But this is the design work only, it doesn't involve any of the underlying logic to website functionality.

Being so many differences I can think of off the top of my head, I would stick with one or the other. If there is too much codebase to re-write everything that is PHP in ASP.net, you may want to look for alternate solutions to Kentico, but that are in PHP.

Comment: The PHP CMS's and the Kentico CMS's are separate, I just need an external media library to be used by both - something that hooks into them seamlessly and allows re-use between them.

Comment: @metalshark I think custom coding a PHP app on a cookieless subdomain, which also tracks approval and version history based on the http-referal value would be the way to go. Unfortunately, this can be suppressed in browsers, especially bots, so I think this is where it breaks. Possibly if multiple *unique* domains were pointed to the same repository it would avoid this, as you could check the domain value rather than the referal value.